# Recycler View not Showing in an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have been making an app that uses a recycler view in an Activity how the contents of the recycler view have not been showing up.
Here my code

pending_complaint.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_pending_complaints"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

pendig_complaint_data.java

```
public class pendig_complaint_data {

    String comp_id;
    String description;

}
```

pending_comp_adapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 6/20/2017.
 */

public class pending_comp_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<pending_comp_adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<pendig_complaint_data> data=new ArrayList<pendig_complaint_data>();
    private Context context;

    public pending_comp_adapter(Context context,List<pendig_complaint_data> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_complaint_custom_row,parent,false);
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        pendig_complaint_data current=data.get(position);
        holder.comp_id1.setText(current.comp_id);
        holder.desc1.setText(current.description);
        Log.e("Daniel1",current.comp_id+" "+data.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView comp_id1;
        TextView desc1;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            comp_id1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complaint_id);
             desc1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.complaint_desc);
        }
    }
}
```

pending_complaints.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 5/23/2017.
 */

public class pending_complaints extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mrecyclerView;
    private pending_comp_adapter adapter;
    List<pendig_complaint_data> data= new ArrayList<pendig_complaint_data>();
    String url="http://192.168.1.186:90/am/pending_complaints.asp?staff_no=";
    String respon;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pending_complaints);

        new get_complaint_data().execute();

        }


    class get_complaint_data extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("STAFF_NO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String staff_no = settings.getString("Staff_no", "");
            url+=staff_no;
            Log.e("Daniel",url);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpHandler sh=new HttpHandler();
            respon=sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(respon.toString().equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Pending Complaints",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            else
            {   Log.e("Daniel",respon);
                String s[]=respon.toString().substring(0,respon.length()-1).split("\\|");
                for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
                {
                    String s1[]=s[i].split("\\*");
                    pendig_complaint_data current=new pendig_complaint_data();
                    current.comp_id=s1[0];
                    ;Log.e("Daniel",current.comp_id);
                    current.description=s1[1];
                    Log.e("Daniel",current.description);
                    data.add(current);
                }
                mrecyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_pending_complaints);
                mrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                adapter=new pending_comp_adapter(getApplicationContext(),data);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                mrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
        }
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

LogCat log

```
06-22 10:28:24.209 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-22 10:28:24.261 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-22 10:28:24.274 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: 249*test|250*test2|251*test3|252*test4|
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: 249
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: test
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: 250
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: test2
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: 251
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: test3
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: 252
06-22 10:28:24.275 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel: test4
06-22 10:28:24.322 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel1: 249 test
06-22 10:28:24.325 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel1: 250 test2
06-22 10:28:24.326 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel1: 251 test3
06-22 10:28:24.329 29457-29457/com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager E/Daniel1: 252 test4
```

Nougat View 
[image: Nougat View]

Marshmallow View
[image: Marshmallow View]

Comment: might be adapter size is zero

Comment: just put a break point @  data.add(current); check the list size.

Comment: Can you please also post what are you getting in response? Will make it easier to help.

Comment: can you able to print the data.size();

Comment: post your response here