# Recycler view not visible in marshmallow but visible in nougat

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I created the Recycler View in Android Application.

It is visible in Android nougat devices but not visible in marshmallow devices

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daniel.bhelstockmanager"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:v1.2') { transitive = true; }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `"not visible"` ?

Comment: Can you  post your layout

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwej8GvUq8gJc20yTFRmSTdscG8/view?usp=sharing
Here is the Link to the view on my Phone
The Android Code is on this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645529/recycler-view-not-showing-in-an-activity
The recycler View is working properly in nougat but not below that

Comment: I am facing same problem, did anyone found any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in Marshmallow 6.0 and below.

Can be solved by using two ways.

1. For RecyclerView

Set RecyclerView Height to wrap_content mine was match_parent. I thought since I have only RecyclerView in my Activity I can set RecyclerView or ScrollView to match_parent, but somehow it's not working nowadays. I remember I was using ScrollView with property match_parent many times.

2. For ScrollView/NestedScrollView
   Set fillViewport property to true.